# Wordpress my first plugin is loading on every site

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and wrote my own Plugin.
Now I have the the problem that my plugin is on every site and overwrite other sites. So the plugin is loading the content on every site.

myplugin.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Gw2  Event Timer
 * Plugin URI: http://localhost/wordpress
 * Description: Ein Guild Wars 2 Timer - beinhaltet alle Weltbosse und die neun HoT Gebiete
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Niklas Grieger
 * Author URI: http://localhost/wordpress
 * License: No License
 */
function event_timer_head() {

    echo "<link href='../wp-content/plugins/gw2EventTimer/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../wp-content/plugins/gw2EventTimer/js/js.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.moongate.pl/event-timers/moment.min.js'></script>

    ";


}

function event_timer_content($content) {
    $content="<div id='event-wrapper' class='event-wrapper'>
    <div class='event-limit'><span class='event-limit-text'>Nächste</span></div>
    <div class='event-pointer'><span class='event-pointer-time'>00:00 UTC</span></div>
    <div style='height:10px; width:100%;'></div>
    </div>";
    return strtolower($content);
}

function event_timer_title($title) {
    $title = str_replace(' ', ' ', $title);
    return $title;
}
function mh_load_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mh_load_my_script' );
add_action('wp_head', 'event_timer_head');
add_filter('the_content', 'event_timer_content');
add_filter('the_title', 'event_timer_title');
?>
```

I think the $content is the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: answer below, please ensure you know how to upvote and accept answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
function event_timer_content($content) {
    $content.="<div id='event-wrapper' class='event-wrapper'>
    <div class='event-limit'><span class='event-limit-text'>Nächste</span></div>
    <div class='event-pointer'><span class='event-pointer-time'>00:00 UTC</span></div>
    <div style='height:10px; width:100%;'></div>
    </div>";
    return strtolower($content);
}
```

You were overwriting rather than adding to content, if the timer is not supposed to appear on every page, you need to define when it should run, i.e. check postid, etc